# How to get post taxonomy url and name in wp_query

Tags: wp-query, categories

I have custom taxonomy (`video-category`) and custom post type (`video`). I want to show taxonomy link and name in my post items in `WP_Query` loop.

I use this to show that, But not working:

```
<?php get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'video-category', ', ' ) ?>
```

My `WP_Query` loop:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'offset'=> 1,
      'posts_per_page'=>2,
      'post_type' => 'video',
    )
);

if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();
       $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
           get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' ); ?>
           <div class="post post-thumb">
           <a class="post-img" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
               <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
           </a>
           <div class="post-body">
               <div class="post-category">
                   <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_the_category()[0]->cat_ID); ?>"><?php get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'video-category', ', ' ) ?>
                   </a>
               </div>
               <h3 class="post-title">
                   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
               </h3>
               <ul class="post-meta">
                   <li><?php the_author(); ?></li>
                   <li><?php the_time( 'j F Y'); ?></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="i5w0Le" aria-hidden="true">
               <span class="z1asCe UIgqBe">
                   <svg focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm-2 14.5v-9l6 4.5-6 4.5z"></path>
                   </svg>
               </span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <?php
       $i++;
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<div class="post-category">
<?php
// @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'video-category' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    $term_links = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_attr( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy ) ) . '">' . __( $term->name ) . '</a>';
    }
    $all_terms = join( ', ', $term_links );
    echo '<span class="terms-' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '">' . __( $all_terms ) . '</span>';
}
?>
</div>
```